# Regular Expression for a 3 digit number in a long text

Tags: regex

I have the following test string. Using `RegEx` I like to extract `200` and `381`.

> 2010-08-12 00:00:01 69.143.116.98 - W3SVC106 STREAM 207.22.66.152 80 GET /includes/scripts.js - 200 0 2258 381 94 HTTP/1.1 www.mercymed.com Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+WOW64;+GoogleT5;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+Media+Center+PC+5.0;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30618;+.NET4.0C) - http://www.mercymed.com/

I used the following pattern, but no luck.
`(?<=\s)[0-9]{3}`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use positive look ahead and look behind to spot the whitespaces.

```
(?<=\s)\d{3}(?=\s)
```

[regexstorm results](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cs%29%5Cd%7B3%7D%28%3F%3D%5Cs%29&i=2010-08-12%2000%3A00%3A01%2069.143.116.98%20-%20W3SVC106%20STREAM%20207.22.66.152%2080%20GET%20%2Fincludes%2Fscripts.js%20-%20200%200%202258%20381%2094%20HTTP%2F1.1%20www.mercymed.com%20Mozilla%2F4.0%2B%28compatible%3B%2BMSIE%2B7.0%3B%2BWindows%2BNT%2B6.0%3B%2BWOW64%3B%2BGoogleT5%3B%2BSLCC1%3B%2B.NET%2BCLR%2B2.0.50727%3B%2BMedia%2BCenter%2BPC%2B5.0%3B%2B.NET%2BCLR%2B3.5.30729%3B%2B.NET%2BCLR%2B3.0.30618%3B%2B.NET4.0C%29%20-%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mercymed.com%2F%60)

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
- (\d{3}) .+ (\d{3}) \d+ HTTP
```

https://regex101.com/r/XB5p2X/2

---

`-` and `HTTP` are used to indicate the "location area" of the needed numbers

Answer (score 1):

@Roman is correct, just minor corrections -

> **1** I hope first number seems response code, so it can be in sure 3 digit. 
>   Second number may be more than 3 digit
>   - (\d{3}) .+ (\d+) \d+ HTTP
>   **2** .+ is greedy we should append ? to remove it's greedy behaviour

Regex should be
- (\d{3}) .+? (\d+) \d+ HTTP

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/XB5p2X/3)